# Jump to a given line number in pgAdmin III

Tags: pgadmin

I wonder whether there is any way to jump to a given line number in the "edit data" window in pgAdmin III.

[image]

I am aware that I can use the sort/filter window to add filters, but I just want to jump.

[image]

Comment: Yet again, Franck, a perfectly reasonable (and what seems to be intuitively obvious) feature that is lacking in pgAdminIII. As usual, should you decide to put in a feature request, I'd be only too happy to chime in with a "me too".

Comment: @Vérace Thanks,  I filed a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Vérace's [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134853/jump-to-a-given-line-number-in-pgadmin-iii/142847#comment253300_134853), I filed a feature request: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1429