# How can I copy the content of a cell in the output pane where the latter is detached from the query window in pgAdmin III?

Tags: pgadmin

How can I copy the content of a cell in the output pane where the latter is detached from the query window in  pgAdmin III?

When the output pane is not detached from the query window, I can use   <kbd>control</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd>, but it doesn't seem to work when it is detached.

Here is a screenshot showing the output pane detached from the query window:

[image]

I use pgAdmin III 1.20.0 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (English).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reasons best known to the designers of PgAdmin3, it's apparently not possible to do this.

The Cut/Copy and Paste options become greyed out when the window is floating. The logic behind this escapes me (wracks brain.... no, no good).

The only thing that I can think of is to use the green write arrow with the floppy and save your data to a file and dig out your data element that way - cumbersome I know. Or, you could just re-dock the window which does work.

If you'd like to file a feature request on the PgAdmin site, I'll gladly file a "me-too" if you provide the link back here.

Comment: Thanks, feature request filed https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1428

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I put the two PRs (Problem Requests - this one and the one [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134853/jump-to-a-given-line-number-in-pgadmin-iii?noredirect=1#comment270905_134853)) on my watch list - I can't see any other way of expressing enthusiasm for a request. It looks like these PRs will be redundant anyway - interesting things afoot with [pgAdmin 4](http://pgsnake.blogspot.ie/2016/04/pgadmin-4-elephant-nears-finish-line.html)...